How to optimize webpack asset modules for Git?
I have a webpack project (with TypeScript) where I want to read some data (xml) files.
For that I am currently using the asset module asset/source:
{
    test: /\.xml/,
    type: 'asset/source',
},

Problem
I have a git repository set up for the project, but changes to the data files lead to incomprehensible diffs since the data files are inlined without line breaks. (line breaks are converted to \\r\\n)
Question
Is it possible to make changes to the data files more readable for Git?
Ideas

keep the formatting (actual linebreaks) in the inlined strings
read the data files without inlining

Webpack Config
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  //devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  mode: "development",
  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.xml/,
        type: 'asset/source',
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};

